# Booking form/Page on Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have been given a website (www.theitalianjob.co.im) and the CMS is Joomla. I have never used Joomla before in my life. I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to figure out how to get a working "Make a Booking" page. I need to add this in as the top menu.

Things this page will need to include, Name, Email, Phone, No of People, Date and Time.

I have had a look with a number of paid plugins but there must be a free way to resolve this?

Much Love,
Website Novice

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Fabrik extension for Joomla. It is free and will let you create pretty in-depth forms and tables.

I used it before to manage an intranet page for the submission, managing, and communication of testing results, of retail promotions at a medium sized business with over 50 locations.

It not only allows you to create custom forms and tables that fit with in the website's theme, but it provides options to incorporate custom css and java snippets to do more advanced functions.

It is very powerful, versatile, well supported in the community, and will give you the chops you need to get the ball rolling with using Joomla.

Did I also mention that it is free.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/fabrik

Answer (score 1):

You can try for example with this free extension, [PBBooking](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/vertical-markets/booking-a-reservations/pbbooking).

Remember that you can change for example the text to adapt the extension to your requirements, here you have some [docs](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla) for language overrides.

Also here you have the main category for [Booking & Reservations](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/vertical-markets/booking-a-reservations) in the Extensions Directory.